# Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection')

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, sql-injection, veracode

After R&D I didn't get solution for this flaw. Please guide me in solving this flaw

**Description**
This database query contains a SQL injection flaw. The function call constructs a dynamic SQL query using a variable derived from user-supplied input. An attacker could exploit this flaw to execute arbitrary SQL queries against the
database.

**Recommendations**
Avoid dynamically constructing SQL queries. Instead, use parameterized prepared statements to prevent the database from interpreting the contents of bind variables as part of the query. Always validate user-supplied input to
ensure that it conforms to the expected format, using centralized data validation routines when possible.

```
public void EditUser(User f)
{
    string connectionString 
        = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    string adm = (f.IsAdmin?"1":"0");
    string phone="",email="";

    if(f.PhoneList.Count > 0)
       phone = f.PhoneList[0].ToString();

    if(f.EmailList.Count > 0)
       email = f.EmailList[0].ToString();

    for(int i = 1; i < f.PhoneList.Count; i++)
       phone = phone + ";" + f.PhoneList[i].ToString();

    for(int i = 1; i < f.EmailList.Count; i++) 
       email = email + ";" + f.EmailList[i].ToString();

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET  is_admin="+adm+",login='"+f.Login+"',passwd='"+f.Password+
             "',firstname='"+f.FirstName+"',lastname='"+f.LastName+"',email='"+email+"',phone='"+phone+"',address='"+f.Address+"' where user_id="+f.UserId;

    conn.Open();
    int affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Are you claiming you couldn't find any information on how to parameterise a query online in your R&D?

Answer (score 7):

Your code builds up the SQL command by appending strings together

```
    cmd.CommandText 
        = "UPDATE Users SET  is_admin="+adm+",login='"+f.Login+"',passwd='"+f.Password+
         "',firstname='"+f.FirstName+"',lastname='"+f.LastName+"',email='"+email+"',phone='"+phone+"',address='"+f.Address+"' where user_id="+f.UserId;
```

Suppose someone called your function with a `User` value where `lastname` equaled

```
"Presser';DROP TABLE Users --"
```

Your SQL command will now destroy the Users table.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx), where MSDN describes how to avoid this problem.